# Excel VBA moving data sets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dataset similar to below and this can go more than 100 rows, I'm hoping to get this data set to separate when column B data does not equal to its above cell (say A and B), the data set then move to the closest coming row of 30th (say row 30 60 90 ... etc) and it also count (B and C).

Meaning, if B is in roll 57, it will insert blank rows so B will go to roll 60, and "C" will then go to row 90 or 120 depending on how many B's were found in column B.

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cell | A | 123 |
| Cell | A | 456 |
| Cell | B | 456 |
| Cell | C | 456 |

The actual dataset looks like this pic.

[image: 1]

Thank you.

I'm not familiar with VBA yet to get start with anything.

Answer (score 1):

Please try.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub demo()
    Dim i As Long, lastVal As String, iCnt As Long
    lastVal = CStr(Cells(1, 2))
    i = 2
    Do While Len(Cells(i, 2)) > 0
        If Not lastVal = CStr(Cells(i, 2)) Then
            If i Mod 30 > 0 Then
                iCnt = 30 - (i Mod 30)
                Cells(i, 1).Resize(iCnt).EntireRow.Insert
                i = i + iCnt
            End If
        End If
        lastVal = Cells(i, 2)
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Taller, thank you very much, this is exactly how I need the formula to be.